# Java: instanceof doesn't compile

Tags: java, operator-keyword, instanceof

I'm a newbie to Java and want to write a method checking if this object is of a sub class of given class <p_SuperClassName>.
Eclipse denies compilation of the following code giving the message that "cls_Super can not be resolved to a type". I don't know why. Do you have a quick answer to this? Thx a lot in advance!

```
protected boolean isOfSubClassOf(String p_SuperClassName) {
    boolean res = false;

    Class<?> cls_Super = null;
    try {
        cls_Super = Class.forName(p_SuperClassName);
        res = (this instanceof cls_Super);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: Did not find class '" + p_SuperClassName + "'.");
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

as described previously

Comment: is cls_Super really defined as a class? in the scope you provided it is a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a Class variable with the `instanceof` keyword, only the literal type name (e.g. `obj instanceof ActualSuperClassName`). With an instance of type `Class` (i.e. `cls_Super`, in your example), you can perform the same test by using the [`Class.isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method, i.e.:

```
res = cls_Super.isInstance(this);
```